# Why does the :hover pseudo class have another selector after it?

Tags: css

I'm having trouble trying to understand why there is a selector after the `:hover` pseudo class, and not before it. How and why does this work?

This works

```
div li:hover > ul 
{
display: block;
}
```

Why wouldn't this work?

```
div li > ul:hover
{
display: block;
}
```

I've done many searches trying to figure out why to put a selector or selectors after it( :hover pseudo class); and the details of how it targets it, but I just can't seem to find any information about it. Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selectors are logically different.

`li:hover > ul` matches a `ul` inside of a hovered `li`.

`li > ul:hover` matches a hovered `ul` inside any `li`.

Your `ul`s are probably hidden by default, so `li > ul:hover` isn't going to match anything.
In contrast, `li:hover > ul` matches the still-hidden `ul` as soon as the `li` is hovered, and shows it.